# Jquery to show block on mouse over

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

Here is the [live](http://www.b2bscriptonline.com/) site where I am doing my stuff. Now in that link you can see there is one section called `Source from Top Global Suppliers` in that section you can see there is a block called `Hot Regions`. Now when you will make hover your mouse you can see it is showing a block with some country's flags.But when you will move your mouse to one of the flag then the box is hiding.But I want that when you will move your mouse to any of those flag still the box will be there. I have followed [this](http://www.alibaba.com/) site for that hover section.

my jQuery code for that block is like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hr-current').mouseover(function() {
      jQuery('#hot-regions').addClass('hr-hover');
    });
    jQuery('.hr-current').mouseout(function() {
      jQuery('#hot-regions').removeClass('hr-hover');
    });
  });
```

**Note**

Here is the link for fiddle
here is the link for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/y53WQ/
I want the result will be exactly like the referenced link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

First, use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) rather than [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

Next, remove the following from your jsfiddle example:

CSS:

```
.hr-hover .hr-current {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Finally, use the following:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hr-current').mouseenter(function() {
      jQuery('#hot-regions').addClass('hr-hover');
    });
    jQuery('#hot-regions').mouseleave(function() {
      jQuery('#hot-regions').removeClass('hr-hover');
    });
  });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/y53WQ/10/

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `mouseout` on the `#hot-regions` :

```
jQuery('#hot-regions').mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hr-hover');
});
```

If fixed it by using mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.hr-current').mouseenter(function() {
      jQuery('#hot-regions').addClass('hr-hover');
    });

    jQuery('#hot-regions').mouseleave(function() {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('hr-hover');
    });

  });
```

See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/y53WQ/2/).

Comment: thanks  for the answer but I want when I will hover on hot regions the box should come which is fine with your fidlle and also the hot regions box should also come to see just like the refernced link http://www.alibaba.com/

Answer (score 0):

live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r6hg8/7/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#hot-regions').mouseenter(function() {
         jQuery(this).addClass('hr-hover');
    });
    jQuery('#hot-regions').mouseleave(function() {
         jQuery(this).removeClass('hr-hover');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks  for the answer but I want when I will hover on hot regions the box should come which is fine with your fidlle and also the hot regions box should also come to see just like the refernced link http://www.alibaba.com/

Comment: I didn't find any difference in reference link and fiddle. Can you point out in detail?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you find any problem compare to reference site, describe it briefly.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. But here I want to tell you is when you will go to http://www.alibaba.com/ You can see there is block called hot regions and when you will hover on it it is showing the flags of other country. Which is you have done in the fiddle, that’s fine. But also in that site you can see when you will hover the hot regions still the hot regions is visible. But in your fiddle there is hot regions and when you will hover you can see the hot regions is going disappeared. that’s I am asking..

Comment: He wants it to remove after the mouse leaves the `.hr-current`, when it is hide. 
The `.hr-hover .current` margin should be replaced by `visibility:hidden` but it neither work...

Comment: @NewBie : Is it working fine ? or any doubt ? Please note that left border is also appearing while hovering in my code.

Comment: @NewBie: DOM's solution is same as mine was. By the way I've improved the solution to match with reference link. comment plz

Comment: @NewBie: In DOM's solution '#hot-regions' left border is not shown on hover. In my solution it remains as it it like in reference link.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like that with `this` and `that` are the div you need to fire the event and to add and remove

```
         $(".ht-current").hover( 
            function(){ 
             $("#hot-regions").addClass('yourHover');
            },
            function(){
             $("#hot-regions").removeClass('yourHover');
            });
```